# Prevent JavaFX Window from Stealing Focus

Tags: java, swing, javafx, awt, awtrobot

I'm trying to make an overlay on the screen using JavaFX and an issue I'm having is that whenever my overlay pops up, it steals focus from whichever program I'm currently in. The issue with this is that my overlay allows the user to simulate keyboard key presses using the robot class (like an on-screen keyboard) and without keeping the focus in the original window, the typed characters have nowhere to go. I've tried setting the modality to none, but that's also the default option and it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Would putting my JavaFX scene in a JFrame work or is there some better way to do it only in JavaFX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
when focused -> compute what you want to 
then call Stage.toBack(); //the currently focused window prior to yours will gain focus back
```

Comment: I am not sure if this worked at the time of writing but it does not work with Java 8u202. In a quick sample app I created a stage that pops up after a delay. I run my sample app and the switch to notepad and start typing. After the JafaFx stage is created (and sent to back) my keystrokes are no longer directed to Notepad. When I press alt-tab to switch to javaFX I can see my keystrokes were captured in the sample app which was hidden behind the notepad window.